# How to use recursive in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to understand how recursion works in haskell, I'm trying to do a function that multiply using a sum

Something like 4 * 5 = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4

My current function is

```
multiplicacao a b 
    | b == 1 = a 
    | otherwise = multiplicacao (a + a) (b-1)
```

if I try to do multiplicacao 7 3 it returns 28

Comment: You are missing an `else` branch. In Haskell, it is a syntax error if you have an `if` that does not have both a `then` branch and an `else` branch. Also, you should try to include any errors you get in your questions. It makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: I only get a parse error

Comment: The code from your edit does not seem to have a parse error, but it also doesn't give the correct answer.  Think about this: What happens when you call it with `1` for `b`? What does it do, exactly (try to think step-by-step what its doing)

Comment: Hi, I'm gonna edit again

Comment: Your code follows the equation `a*b = (a+a)*(b-1)`, which is not true in general. Try fixing that equation, e.g. moving the `+a` part somewhere else.

Comment: You here basically performa `a*2^(b-1)`, since you each time pass `a+a`...

Comment: `4 * 5 = 4  + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4` doesn't demonstrate recursion. `4 * 5 = 4 + 4 * 4` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here that you recurse with `(a+a)` as new value to multiply. Indeed, if you for example use `multiplicacao 7 3`, you get:

```
multiplicacao 7 3
  -> multiplicacao (7+7) (3-1)
  -> multiplicacao (7+7) 2
  -> multiplicacao ((7+7)+(7+7)) (2-1)
  -> multiplicacao ((7+7)+(7+7)) 1
  -> ((7+7)+(7+7))
  -> 14 + 14
  -> 28
```

each recursive step, you thus multiply `a` with `2` and subtract one from `b`, so that means that you are calculating *a×2<sup>b-1</sup>*.

You should keep the original `a` and thus each time add `a` to the accumulator. For example with:

```
multiplicacao :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
multiplicacao a = go 0
  where go n 0 = n
        go n b = go (n+a) (b-1)
```

This will only work if `b` is a *natural* number (so zero or positive).

You can however work with an implementation where you check if `b` is even or odd, and in the case it is even multiply `a` by two. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you explain to me what  "multiplicacao :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a" does?

Comment: @MackProgram: it is the type signature: it says that the first item has a type `a` that is an instance of `Num` (so `Double`, `Int`, etc.), and the second of type `b` that is an `Integral` type (so `Int`, `Integer`, `Int16`, etc.), the result is of type `a`, so the same type as the first item.